# Symfony assetic custom path issue

Tags: symfony

I am exploring the option of refactoring a codebase into Symfony. The application in question is built on a lot of Sencha front end code, custom PHP framework, etc.

I created a bundle AeroBundle and dropped my entire legacy app into a folder called "_Legacy" of this bundle.

I am trying to implement the layout template and wish to call the first of many CSS/JS files using something like:

```
    {% stylesheets
        "@AerospaceBundle/_Legacy/public/common/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" 
    %}
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

But I am getting nothing???

Moving my aassets around according to Symfony (ie: Resources) will make continued development and refactoring a HUGE challenge. Ideally I can keep my legacy app contained in one folder so as changes are made I can literally drop them in to this legacy folder - this starts with resolving client assets with something like above.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this? I need to explicitly indicate the internal bundle paths for resources - I do not want to move my JS/CSS into the bundles Resources directory - unless it is absolutely required - in which case I may have to re-think my strategy.

EDIT | I just realized this snippet is a block and this is being done in the base template so thats likely why its not rendering anything? How do I include a single stylesheet from a custom directory?

Answer (score 0):

With assetic, you can use something like that

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
    assets:
            merged_js:
                inputs:
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/jquery.min.js"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/angular.min.js"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/js/app.js"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/tinymce/tinymce/tinymce.js"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/tinymce/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js"
            merged_css:
                inputs:
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/custom.css"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css"
                    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/tinymce/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css"
                filters: [cssrewrite]
```

and then on twig

```
{% stylesheets  '@merged_css'  %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
{% javascripts '@merged_js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But to be honest, lately I have been doing such things on preprocessors like gulp.
That way my server side code is clean from client side stuff that do not do much at runtime.
Not to mention that assetic support is slowly dropped and symfony is moving towards a preprocessor with encore and webpack